# How can i check whether or not a condition is met for every vector in a numpy array, and get a new array with only the vectors that met the condition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, conditional-statements

I am making a ray tracer in python and want to speed it up using numpy. I am having some trouble with checking whether a condition is met by a vector in an array.
Specifically, in the vector there is a value that is the discriminant of a function. I use this for collisions. After i have calculated the discriminant in every vector, I want to get a list that only contains the vectors that have a discriminant >= 0. How can I do this with numpy?

Suppose you have an array, and in the array there are ten vectors that contain three values. The Discriminant is at index 0. How would i do the condition checking?

I have tried doing

```
newArray = array[array[0] >= 0]
```

But this gives the error `IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 10 but corresponding boolean dimension is 3`
I know this can be done with a simple for-loop, but i really don't want to do that since it'll slow down my program.
I do not know what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What about: `array[array[:, 0] >= 0]`?

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs Thanks! This does go in the right direction but this only checks wheter the vector doesn't contain a number below zero at all for some reason. I only want to check wheter or not the value at index 0 of every vector is >= 0.

Comment: I assumed @Chrysophylaxs answer was correct, also.  Please give some sample input and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @FrankYellin My bad, this is my first question ever on this site. I shall do that next time!